# Estimating number of lattice points on a hyperbola

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, factoring, integer-lattices

Given a hyperbola $$y = x + \frac n x \tag 1$$ and a range $x \in (a,b)$, how do we find **the number of lattice points** lying in the range that the hyperbola passes through? A lattice point is a point $(x,y)$ on the coordinate plane with both $x$ and $y$ integers.

One approach is to factor $n$ and then take $x$ as the divisors of $n$ that lie in the range $(a,b)$.

**Example:** Find lattice points of $$y = x + \frac {527} x \tag 2$$ in the range $x \in (0,20)$. We factor $527 = 17 \times 31$. The divisors are $1, 17, 31$ and $527$ and only $x \in \{1, 17\}$ are in the range $(0,20)$. Therefore, they are the $x$-coordinates of the lattice points of interest. We substitute in Eqn. (2) to get $(1, 528), (17, 48)$ as the lattice points.

**Question 1:** This method works when $n$ is of a manageable size and can be factored easily. **What do we do when $n$ is large?**

**Question 2:** Even if we are not able to find the exact lattice points, is there a way to

1. estimate **the number of solutions** in the range (or)
2. even just the **existence of solutions in the range** (i.e., yes/no answer for the existence question)

Assume that we are given the search range $x \in (a,b)$.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? You already note that your question is equivalent to asking for the number of factors of $n$ in the range $(a,b)$. Already for the particular range $(1,n)$ this is stronger than asking whether $n$ is prime, which is notoriously difficult.

Comment: I am not sure. I found this: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LatticePointsUnderAHyperbola/ which seems related and uses Dirichlet's estimate for points under a hyperbola. I was wondering if we could cleverly construct a set of shifted hyperbolae and build an estimate using inclusion/exclusion principle.

Comment: Granted, there's a big difference between points under a hyperbola and on a hyperbola, however I am looking for any ideas.